# SnakeYAML formatting - remove YAML curly brackets

Tags: java, string, snakeyaml

I have a code that is dumping a linkedhashmap into a YAML object

```
public class TestDump {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        values.put("one", 1);
        values.put("two", 2);
        values.put("three", 3);

        DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
        options.setIndent(2);
        options.setPrettyFlow(true);
        Yaml output = new Yaml(options);

        File targetYAMLFile = new File("C:\\temp\\sample.yaml");
        FileWriter writer =null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(targetYAMLFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        output.dump(values, writer);
    }
}
```

But the output looks like this

```
{
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}
```

is there a way to set this to something like this

```
  one: 1
  two: 2
  three: 3
```

Although the first one is a valid yaml..I wanted the output format to be like the second one.

Comment: You should accept your own answer to this question. Please consider upvoting my answer as a secondary approach

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like this is just some configuration via [DumperOptions](http://javadox.com/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.8/org/yaml/snakeyaml/DumperOptions.html):

```
public class TestDump {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        values.put("one", 1);
        values.put("two", 2);
        values.put("three", 3);

        DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
        options.setIndent(2);
        options.setPrettyFlow(true);
        // Fix below - additional configuration
        options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
        Yaml output = new Yaml(options);

        File targetYAMLFile = new File("C:\\temp\\sample.yaml");
        FileWriter writer =null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(targetYAMLFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        output.dump(values, writer);
    }
}
```

This will solve my problem